# How can I create a script for a popup button on cell value change in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript

I am still basic level in javascript and have spent hours searching and testing scripts but none are giving me results. I need a script that will create a popup warning upon cell change reaching "X". This is roughly where I finally stopped trying:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range=e.range;
  var column=range.getColumn();
  var row=range.getRow();
  var status=range.getValue();
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(column===45 && row>1){
    range.setAlert

    var response=sh.alert('Warning!','Employee has used Maximum allowed 
hours, do you wish to proceed?',sh.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  }
}
```

I keep receiving an error about the range, if I input rows/columns or the actual like C2:C10 I get a different error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Also, is there a way to ensure this populates for that one cell, that instance, and not each time an instance occurs in the same column under the same criteria? Basically, the cells in one column all need the script to search, just not repeat by accident.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share the error messages you are receiving in each cases. Also notice that you need to test against 'status' (=actual edited value) or you will end up firing alerts every time user makes an edit, no matter what the value.

Comment: This is the error I am receiving:   TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")